# Trying to parse xml in Windows Phone 7.8 app but getting null value?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I am trying to parse a xml that I got as response to webservice response the xml is shown below

```
<GeneralSearchResponse>
<serverDetail></serverDetail>
<exceptions exceptionCount="1"></exceptions>
<clientTracking height="19" type="logo" width="106"></clientTracking>
<searchHistory></searchHistory>
<categories matchedCategoryCount="1" returnedCategoryCount="1">
<category id="0">
<name>bart</name>
<categoryURL>http://www.shopping.com/bart/products?oq=bart&linkin_id=7000610
</categoryURL>
<items matchedItemCount="1045" pageNumber="1" returnedItemCount="5">
<product id="130506037"></product>
<product id="104483377"></product>
<offer featured="false" id="tp-VCdOoO1RL6xICeRONqg==" smartBuy="false" used="false"></offer>
<offer featured="false" id="12evWWi57lddzFufngUWsg==" smartBuy="false" used="false"></offer>
<product id="96754577"></product>
</items>
<attributes matchedAttributeCount="5" returnedAttributeCount="5"></attributes>
<contentType>hybrid</contentType>
</category>
<intActualCategoryCount>4</intActualCategoryCount>
</categories>
<relatedTerms></relatedTerms>
</GeneralSearchResponse>
```

But when I am trying to parse using following code I am not able to get any descend or any node

```
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
var xEle = xDoc.Root.Descendants("categories");
```

But xEle is not having any categories. Please let me know what is the issue??

Comment: Are you sure that's the *exact* XML - no namespaces involved?

Comment: Yes there is namespace  xmlns="urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com"

Comment: Well that's the problem then. But please in future make your question actually match your problem - it reduces the guesswork involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your XML has a default namespace - so the elements in it are in that namespace. The methods which find elements in LINQ to XML are namespace sensitive. You want:

```
XNamespace ns = "urn:types.partner.api.shopping.com";
XDocument xDoc = new XDocument();
xDoc = XDocument.Parse(data);
var xEle = xDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "categories");
```